# How to increase font/text size of wordcloud in highcharts in angular 7

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am using wordcloud of highcharts in angular 7,It is working fine but when I want to increase its text size of the word which is very small,I am getting the error that 'Highcharts.seriesTypes does not exist in typeof...' Here is the code below

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import * as exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
import * as exportdata from 'highcharts/modules/export-data';
import wordCloud from "highcharts/modules/wordcloud.js";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function (relativeWeight) {
    var maxFontSize = 25;
    // Will return a fontSize between 0px and 25px.
    return Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight); 
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'wordcloud',
        data: data,
        name: 'Occurrences'
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Wordcloud of Lorem Ipsum'
    }
});
};
}
```

### app.component.html

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize all of the modules, for example:

```
import wordCloud from "highcharts/modules/wordcloud.js";
wordCloud(Highcharts)
```

---

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module

Comment: I followed this docs and tried all possibilities but still that error is not going.

Comment: Hi @UIAPPDEVELOPER, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? For example: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsdvms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts    I tried to reproduce a demo here but due to angular version issue wordcloud is not working in demo.

Comment: I have created an example with wordcloud series here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7erkq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Now paste this code ----Highcharts.seriesTypes.wordcloud.prototype.deriveFontSize = function (relativeWeight) {
   var maxFontSize = 25;
  // Will return a fontSize between 0px and 25px.
  let rweight = Math.floor(maxFontSize * relativeWeight);
  let size = rweight < 8? 10: rweight
  return size
}; --- before Line 16 Highcharts.chart('container', {.... and hover on seriesTypes , same error I am getting on compilation error.  I am adding this code to visible all the fonts properly when my max weight is 500 and min weight 4

Comment: I have created separate demo with error https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vdfqvj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER The TS error is caused by using a private function that is not a part of documentation and not a part of highcharts.d.ts. The fastest solution is to cast to `any` like `(Highcharts as any).seriesTypes...`. If you want to add the missing TS definitions then you could check the docs for extending TS defs in here: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/highcharts-typescript-beta#extending-highcharts-in-typescript

Comment: I tried this as you mentioned (Highcharts as any).seriesTypes,its not working even in doc there is no such types of declaration

Comment: @UIAPPDEVELOPER The lack of types is resolved by `as any` casting in any case in TS. If you want to have the type then you should add it as explained in the docs linked in my previous comment because you are trying to access a property that is private and not documented. Here's working (no error) demo based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-htxr6j?file=src/app/app.component.ts